# How to create multiple instances of a Subject in Angular2?

Tags: angular, observable, subject

I have 2 services within my app. I use `Subject` to emmit data for all application. But there is a problem i have only 1 instance of a `Subject`. I have `StateService` where i need 3 independent instances of a `Subject`:

```js
constructor(
  public currentActorSubject: Subject<string>,
  public teamRoleSubject: Subject<string>,
  public teamIdSubject: Subject<string>
) {

}
```

And `ConnectionService` where i need 1 instance of a `Subject`:

```js
constructor(
  private stateService: StateService,
  public participantsSubject: Subject<any>
) {

}
```

I have 2 different **subscribe()** methods to 2 (to my mind) different instances of a `Subject`:

```js
this.stateService.currentActorSubject.subscribe(currentActor => {
  this.currentActor = currentActor;
});
this.connectionService.participantsSubject.subscribe(participants => {
  this.participants = participants;
});
```

But when i run an application and check, i find there is 1 instance that receive all data.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't make any sense to me. Can you please explain what problem you're actually trying to solve? If you new more than one `Subject` than just call `new Subject()` more than once ;-)

Comment: Are you using Subject like a model? Sorry I'm trying to understand your code.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, it helps, thank you.